# Error when connecting to MYSQL Database (NodeJS, socket.io, express)

Tags: mysql, node.js, express, socket.io

me and a friend just started to work on a little App. It uses NodeJS (with Socket.io and Express). We're kind of new into NodeJS and thus can't really comprehend why we get the error we get. Every inch of help is appreciated :)

Here's the code:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var serv = require('http').Server(app);

app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    res.sendFile(__dirname + '/client/index.html');
});
app.use('/client', express.static(__dirname + '/client'));

serv.listen(2000);
console.log("Server started!");
var io = require('socket.io')(serv,{});


var md5 = require('md5');
var mysql = require('mysql');
var dbconn = mysql.createConnection({
    host: "mySERVER",
    user: "myUSER",
    password: "myPASSWORD",
    database: "myDBNAME"
});


dbconn.connect(function(err) {
    if (err) throw err; //THE ERROR IS THROWN HERE
});

io.sockets.on("connection", function(socket) {

    socket.on("register", function(obj){
        var sql = 'INSERT INTO users (name, password) VALUES ("' + obj.name + '", "' + md5(obj.password) + '")';

        dbconn.query(sql, function (err, result) {
            if (err) throw err;
            console.log("Result: " + result);

        });

    });
});
```

And here's the Error Message:

```
Error: connect ECONNREFUSED mySERVER:3306
at Object.exports._errnoException (util.js:1018:11)
at exports._exceptionWithHostPort (util.js:1041:20)
at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1086:14)
--------------------
at Protocol._enqueue (PROJECTPATH\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\Protocol.js:145:48)
at Protocol.handshake (PROJECTPATH\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\Protocol.js:52:23)
at Connection.connect (PROJECTPATH\node_modules\mysql\lib\Connection.js:130:18)
at Object.<anonymous> (PROJECTPATH\app.js:32:8)
at Module._compile (module.js:570:32)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:579:10)
at Module.load (module.js:487:32)
at tryModuleLoad (module.js:446:12)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:438:3)
at Module.runMain (module.js:604:10)
```

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

It's a database connection error. You're mysql host and/or port are wrong.

Make sure the information passed to the `mysq.createConnection` function in the code below are correct:

```
var dbconn = mysql.createConnection({
    host: "mySERVER",
    user: "myUSER",
    password: "myPASSWORD",
    database: "myDBNAME"
});
```

Comment: I am 100% certain that those are correct, I checked it with several different users, checked the mysql port on my server and so on.
Plus all of the Data worked perfectly in PHP

Comment: what about your `/etc/hosts` file, any entry for 'mySERVER' ?

Comment: `# --- BEGIN PVE ---
myServer
# --- END PVE ---`

so yes i guess, the ip is correct in there